# How to assign a split path to different columns?

Tags: excel, powershell

I wanted to get a file path like :
C:\Users\username\Desktop
and split them up in columns for an excel file ie:

```
Root | sub folder1| sub_folder2|subfolder3
C:\  |Users       |    username|Desktop
```

I tried assigning them individually to different variables but some path's are longer than others

I tried doing

```bsh
$final = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {

    $path = 'C:\Users\Username\ Desktop'
[PSCustomObject]@{‘Name’ = $path;'Roots' = $path -split '\\' } 

}

$final|Select-Object Name, Roots | Export-excel '.\testfile.xlsx' -append
```

I'm not getting an error but when I open the excel file, only one file shows up and the roots aren't separated into different columns

Comment: CSV or Excel files seem to be an inappropriate choice for your purpose. CSV or Excel files are made for structured data. The structure should be regular. The first element of the data defines the amount of columns created. What's the actual purpose of this task?

Comment: The purpose is to get the gathered data I exported to CSV and then organize it but in order for me to organize it using excel features, I had to convert it to a xlsx file. I want to use the delimiter to organize the depth of the folders I found.

Comment: Hmmm ... that does not answer my question ... actually. You might update you question with more information about what's the initial situation and what's the expected result?

Comment: Not sure what wasn't clear but if you're asking what I am trying to achieve is that I want to be able to split up that path using a delimeter and somehow organize the results horizontally into different columns in a csv file rather than vertically into a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit easier way to go about this using get-item:

```
get-item c:\windows\system32 | select root, parent, basename | export-csv c:\folder.csv
```

Comment: Does it go 3 volumes into depth with the directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

Another working example no matter how many tree level your directory :

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop'

$Splited=$path -split '\\'

$Object=[pscustomobject]@{Root=$Splited[0]}
$Splited[1..($Splited.Length)] | foreach -Begin{$i=0} -Process {$i++; Add-Member -InputObject $Object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Sub Folder $i" -Value $_ }

$Object | export-csv "c:\temp\Result.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Would this split it up  in the csv into separate columns as well?

Comment: ahh got it!! :D Thank you so much!